# Android Nougat 7.1.1 broadcastReceiver don't receive the action WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION

Tags: java, android

i am working on Nexus 5X android Nougat 7.1.1 on BroadCastReceiver with action WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION defined in AndroidManifests.xml, but is don't work properly, is works only when i opened the wifi settings page.

Note: Since i have updated the device version from 7.0.0 to 7.1.1 this happening with me , before that, everything was working properly.

WiifiBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class WifiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if(action.equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanResult = new ArrayList<>();
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
               wifiScanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifests.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.TestApp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".WifiBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

**It's the system error of the android 7.1.1.**

Some devices have been updated to Android 7.1.2 where this error was fixed, another ones now have rollback to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the GPS on your device.Then it will work.